# if pattern found in column add specific value to next column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 2 columns and I would like that, if a specific value is found in the second column, a "1" will be added to the third column. If the pattern is not found, a "0" should be added to the third column.
If tried the following code but it is not working...

```
if grep -F "PATTERN" myfile.txt; then
        awk '{print $1, $2, $3 == 1}'
else
        awk '{print $1, $2, $3 == 0}’
fi
```

My input looks like this:

```
ID1    Pop1
ID2    Pop1
ID3    PATTERN
```

And my desired output would be:

```
ID1    Pop1    0
ID2    Pop1    0
ID3    PATTERN    1
```

Comment: You said your file only has 2 columns. So exactly what you want is adding a new entry to the next row in the third column which is getting created? Or by chance does it mean mathematical addition to values in third row?

Comment: Yes, I only have 2 columns and when I find the pattern I'm looking for, the program should add in the same line a third column with a "1", else, with a "0"

Comment: I believe you need to give some more details. Like sample input and sample output for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: looks better?? ;)

Answer (score 2):

This will match for a string containing PATTERN and add 1 or 0 as last column. `FS` is file seperator. You can use `" "` or **tab** as you desire.

```
awk '{if ( $2 ~ /PATTERN/ ) {print $0 FS "1"} else {print $0 FS "0"}}' file
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. I am new to awk, so mine is not that good.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you :) It is working!

Answer (score 2):

wrt `$3 == 1` in your script where I assume you were trying to assign the value `1` to `$3` - like in many languages, `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment.

```
$ awk '{print $0, ($2=="PATTERN")}' file
ID1    Pop1 0
ID2    Pop1 0
ID3    PATTERN 1
```

or if you like golf:

```
$ awk '{$3=($2=="PATTERN")}1' file
ID1 Pop1 0
ID2 Pop1 0
ID3 PATTERN 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An short `awk` version

```
awk '$2~/PATTERN/?$0=$0FS 1:$0=$0FS 0' file
ID1    Pop1 0
ID2    Pop1 0
ID3    PATTERN 1
```

If `PATTERN` found add `1`, else add `0`.  Default action is print.

```
$2~/PATTERN/ ?$0=$0FS 1 :$0=$0FS 0
---Test----- --True?--- --False?--
```